# Como fazer uma rotina de migração de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suponha-se que tenho um model de cadastro e outro de usuários. Como fazer com que cada registro de cadastro seja enviado para o usuários? Isso também deve ser feito a cada novo registro que for criado no cadastro, ele deve ser migrado para o model usuário.

Sou novo em Rails, não tenho muito conhecimento de Active Record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para criar essa "migração" automática você deve usar um dos callbacks fornecidos pelo Active Record(AR) dentro do seu Model. A escolha depende da lógica do seu negócio. O AR fornece vários gatilhos ou momentos de entrada. Consulte o link abaixo:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

---

O código abaixo faz o que você quer.

> ...deve ser feito a cada novo registro que for criado no cadastro...

O objeto do tipo Usuario será criado logo após a criação do objeto Cadastro por meio do gatilho/callback **after_create :copia_para_usuario**

Lembre-se: o método **copia_para_usuario** será executado automaticamente **se** o objeto cadastro for criado. Ou seja, se o objeto do tipo Usuario não for criado então um objeto do tipo Cadastro não será criado pelo método **copia_para_usuario**.

Mas atenção, o código abaixo não garante a criação de usuário. Para isso você deve englobar a operação toda(criação de cadastro e criação de usuário) numa **transaction**, mas isso está fora do escopo da pergunta.

```
# carregando bibliotecas
require 'sqlite3'
require "active_record"

# Conectando ao sqlite3
# Obs: rodando banco na memória ao invés de gravar em arquivo;
# o banco desaparece ao final da execução
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    adapter: 'sqlite3',
    database: ':memory:'
)

# detalhes do esquema do banco
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :cadastros do |t| # o nome da tabela deve estar no plural
    t.string :nome
    t.string :sobrenome
    t.string :email
  end

  create_table :usuarios do |t| # o nome da tabela deve estar no plural
    t.string :nome_completo
    t.string :email
  end
end

# Model Cadastro
class Cadastro < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Método que deve ser executado automaticamente(callback) 
  # depois que o objeto é criado(after_create)
  after_create :copia_para_usuario

  # Implementação
  def copia_para_usuario
    usuario = Usuario.new
    # Concatenando nome e sobrenome
    usuario.nome_completo = self.nome + ' ' + self.sobrenome
    usuario.email = self.email
    usuario.save
  end
end

# Model Usuário
class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base

end

# Criando dois objetos do tipo Cadastro
cadastro1 = Cadastro.create!(nome: 'Bento', sobrenome: 'Carneiro',
                             email:'vampiro@brasileiro.com' )
cadastro2 = Cadastro.create!(nome: 'Conde', sobrenome: 'Dracula', 
                             email:'conde@dracula.com' )

# Listando todos os cadastros
puts Cadastro.pluck(:id, :nome, :sobrenome, :email)

puts '-'*10 # separador

# Listando usuarios que foram "migrados" automaticamente
puts Usuario.pluck(:id, :nome_completo, :email)
```

Output do script:

```
-- create_table(:cadastros)
-> 0.0605s
-- create_table(:usuarios)
-> 0.0009s
1
Bento
Carneiro
vampiro@brasileiro.com
2
Conde
Dracula
conde@dracula.com
----------
1
Bento Carneiro
vampiro@brasileiro.com
2
Conde Dracula
conde@dracula.com
```